# Suspension from review processes

Tags: support, review-suspension

I am posting this as my explanation as to why was my review done wrong by me that lead to me having ban that has been set to expire on November 21.

Review in question is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26693953

What I did wrong was, I overlooked the changes in text that were made and just accepted the edit. That has been my 551st review and I just caught a moment where I didn't pay attention.

I guess this post is also my plea for getting unbanned, so I can resume with helping the community with my effort.

This wasn't my first ban, I had some earlier because of some Triage mistakes, and bans were totally justified, and I guess it built up the penalty time to a lot.

Since I got new privileges for reviewing, I have been learning how to do so. Especially, reviewing editing of posts and other actions.
Reviewing editing of posts has been a great deal of my activity, and I liked it because it made some much sense for my OCD to add syntax coloring and formatting posts, thus making it more readable and easier for people to understand (taking this from my experience when reading badly formatted questions).

Comment: You were review banned on July 16 for failing multiple audits, and you didn't bring this up until now, which makes it very troublesome to retrieve the failed audits since mod tools only show up to the past 30 days of audit history.

Comment: Ok, disregard the up comments, i just figured out you said "July", but I read June, when i was banned for Triage, you are saying about the this current one. I just didnt have guts to ask for unban, because of previous ban.

Comment: @MarioPetrovic - So you have been reviewed banned multiple times.  You are aware of those mistakes, and this most recent ban, per your own words, is it was justified.  What exactly is your question though?  You have had a moderator share their concerns about lifting the review ban early.  If you want those concerns to be meet, my suggestion is to submit an answer explaining what mistakes were made and indicating what the correct course of action should have been.  **You are indeed correct, the ban duration increased, because of your continued mistakes in the review queue.**

Comment: @SecurityHound Thanks for your comment. Well this post was my explanation about what happened in that review, and asking if there is a way i could get unbanned. As i mentioned above my mistake was that i wasn't paying attention on that review, and i overlooked that the actual changes that i approved were damaging the post. There is no excuse for that mistake of course. About what you said up there, you are suggesting that i post an answer here on my question explaining the what mistakes were made and indicating what the correct course of action should have been?

Comment: Yes;  It’s better than an unformatted comment

Answer (score 3):

So this is my additional information about this matter.

The review that I failed in question was my oversight while I was going through the suggested edits part.

My mistake was that I overlooked that suggested edit, and I approved it despite it being damaging to the original post.

My ban was initiated on 17th July 2020, and since then I haven't made a post about this because I didn’t have the guts to ask for unbanning, since that was a justified ban.

And after some time doing things like manual edits, formatting, and upvoting, I just wanted to get back in the reviewing feature; that makes it way easier. So this is just a judgement call from anyone with authority, and as I said, I don’t have any complaints about the ban at all.

Answer (score -4):

The text changes made to the title actively hurt its comprehension. Furthermore, the edit added misspelled words. Next, the edit added words to the standard error phrase `307 Temporary Redirect` which also made no sense.

There is not a single subedit within this suggested edit which adds to the question. In fact, quite the opposite, every action hurts the quality of the question. IMO this is a proper review and the wrong decision was made.

Comment: I don't think the OP is claiming their review was in any way correct.

Comment: Yes, the review that i approved was actually incorrect and the ban was justified.