# Is my Review privileges suspension justified

Tags: support, review-suspension

I got my Review privileges suspended just now because of 4 rejected Suggested edits reviews by a moderator.

These are rejected review references:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30676787
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30678208
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30680994
4. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30681719

I went over all four and can't seem to find what I did wrong here.
Can anyone tell me how I made these questions worse by approving these 4 Suggested edits.

I am not calling out the moderator that rejected my reviews, just trying to make sense what happened. It could be an oversight on my side, sorry if it was.

**Elaboration of reviews**

Review **1.** was a regular formatting of code with corrected indentations.
**2, 3 and 4** were regular inline code highlighting in text.

Comment: If you're making an edit then address all the problems. In 4 you add uneeded emphasis to text, there is literally no need for that, and leave the noise in that you should have removed. In 3 you don't add make any inline code to anything, just make a few characters to be code that aren't... Don't misuse the inline code markdown. Most of those changes are completely superfluous.

Comment: Your use of code formatting in this post for *"`Suggested edits`"* is not helping your case.

Comment: I totally agree with your comments. Thanks for giving feedback on my question.

Comment: At the very least, I would have rejected the first review because it didn’t fix the capitalisation or punctuation errors in the title or body of the text. If you are going to make an edit and put it in the queue, it really needs to at least try and fix all the problems with the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one doesn't fix indentation, it changes from 4 to 2 spaces, changes quotes, and introduces semicolons, and is a useless edit. Doesn't improve readability, it changes the formatting to a different of what I assume React struggles with as well; [an obnoxious amount of standards](https://xkcd.com/927/). We don't need edits that get into formatting standard wars when the code is otherwise formatted sanely, given the standard it was originally written in.

The second introduces unnecessary code formatting, and same with the third. The second also introduces code formatting of a language, which isn't appropriate use of code formatting; see links at the end.

The fourth introduces unnecessary bold, which actively degrades readability and [ignores another glaring problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561).

Other relevant discussions on editing policies:

- [User adding excessive bolding in otherwise good edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327171/6296561) (in particular: "**If the improvement from the edit is much greater than the distractions from the bold**, then approving/improving it is fine. But in the example suggestion linked in the question, the distraction of the bold far outweighs the grammar fixes." -- the latter sentence holds here as well, for that particular edit)
- [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/6296561)

Comment: Hey Zoe, thanks for come here to help me understand your reviews. This is very informative. Robert was very helpful with the other answer. I agree 100% with you after reading answers here. I will try and improve my review skills definitely. If you have any more important posts like the ones you mentioned, please leave a comment here, or even better some grouping of these kind of posts. 
The thing that remains, my suspension will last 1 year, is there a way i can get back into reviewing? 1 year is a long time, and i want to contribute as much as i can, but in a improved way.

Comment: You do have a number of previous suspensions, but as far as I can tell, none of them are from suggested edits. That typically doesn't impact the duration (i.e. all review suspensions are equal, and extend the length regardless of what queue caused the suspension), but I digress. I'm somewhat basing my system on Sam's system, back when he was still active, which [does allow appeals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394684/reflection-on-temporary-ban-from-review-queue#comment760308_394684). You're showing reflection, which is a lot more than can be expected from the

Comment: average suspended reviewer, so I'll go ahead and unsuspend you this time; as for resources, I'm planning to make a list, but I haven't gotten that far yet. You can still find most of it here on meta  with a few searches (or by asking if you can't find any relevant posts, or just in general) and on the privilege pages for the various review queues. Just don't forget that [there's no shame in clicking "skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/6296561) if you're in doubt. Do be more careful in the future though

Comment: Hey Zoe. Thanks for getting back to me and for taking your time to put someone on a better course.
 And based on discussion here i definitely need to improve my activities with posts from the past that give more context. Also thanks for putting suspension down.

Answer (score 10):

1. Don't [change the code in a question beyond formatting it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). What you've approved is much more than changes to formatting as single quotes have been changed to double quotes.
2. [don't code format words that aren't code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text).
3. is the same as 2.
4. Adds some random bolding to something that doesn't need it and doesn't improve readability. It also doesn't fix everything wrong with the post as it fails to remove the superfluous

> Thanks everyone for your valuable time

I note also you used backticks for words that aren't code in this question itself. I've corrected that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert, this is very informative. I have been reviewing for some time, Suggested edits more so than other things, but haven't went through there posts that you mentioned above. And based on these arguments i agree 100% with rejection of my review. I guess the question is, should i wait for my suspension to run out or apply for some removal, because the suspension will last for one year?

Comment: Generally suspensions double in length so a one year suspension is usually preceded by a six month suspension etc etc. So if you didn't learn anything all the previous times you were suspended why should moderators believe that this time you're going to immediately transform into an excellent reviewer from your previous role of "making extra work for moderators"

Comment: *"because the suspension will last for one year?"* If your suspension is a year then this is t a one off instance, I would suggest that you've had several Suspensions over the years.

Comment: I see your point. I agree with the rationale of it. Just thinking that positive track record in between two suspensions is maybe not taken into consideration when deciding what the length should be. But i respect the rules. I will try improving my reviewing by reading the suggested posts. Thank you for your time Robert, this meant a lot to my further contribution.

Comment: Yes, that is true @Larnu . In my last comment in mentioned something about track record in between suspensions, and that it maybe should affect the suspension length. But again, i respect the rules and the community. Thanks for your time and effort Larnu. I will try and work on my review skills.

Comment: It is taken into consideration. If you are suspended and then are not for some time the next suspension will be *half* the length of the prior suspension. On the other hand, if you keep getting suspended shortly after it being removed the suspension leagth **doubles**, @MarioPetrovic . The fact you are up to a year means you have been getting multiple concurrent suspensions shortly after one another.

Comment: Got it, it is subjective on my side to say it is not when it is, but that is because a year is long time in general :) . My last suspension expired about 9 months ago. Again, thanks for taking your time to give me feedback. I really appreciate the work people give into this community.

Comment: @Mario - Most users are never review suspended let alone multiple times. You should have came here for advice after the second suspension. Multiple suspensions indicate a failure on your part to understand what is an acceptable edit. Looks like you forgot you said your suspension was going to end this year in November last year [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400540/suspension-from-review-processes) over a year ago. Looks like a pattern of not learning what is an acceptable edit and what isn’t an acceptable edit.